# autoincrement counter doesnt reset when no commit hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate and i am inserting a new data but i am not committing it. But when i repeat the process is shows the auto-increment value to be increased even when i didnt commit the transaction.

```
Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession(); 
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
VoucherDetail voucherDetail = new VoucherDetail();              
voucherDetail.setVoucher(voucher);
voucherDetail = (VoucherDetail) save(voucherDetail2, session, transaction);
//i commented these statements so i don't commit(for testing) 
//session.flush();              
//transaction.commit();
//session.close();

//Then i rollback and flush session for assurity
if(session.isOpen()){
        session.flush();    
        transaction.rollback();                                 
        session.close();
}

//My save function
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public PAK save(ED newInstance, Session session, Transaction transaction) {        
    try {           

        session.saveOrUpdate(newInstance);           
        System.out.println("--------Transaction Committed");
        return (PAK) newInstance;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        try {
            session.merge(newInstance);                                  
            return (PAK) newInstance;
        } catch (HibernateException e1) {
            LOG.error(GD.class.getName(), e1);
        }

        LOG.error(GD.class.getName(), e);
    }           
    return null;
}
```

Now when i look at the voucherDetail object after save. It shows me my autoincrement column name SNo with e.g value = 4. But since i dont commit the transaction when i repeat this process , next time the counter should again show 4 after save, but it shows 5. Why does it keep it in it's memory and how do i remove it.it happens even when i stop and restart the server. it keeps the value. i can't understand why . Kinda new to hibernate

Comment: transaction is on database side. if you increment in your program and assign the counter, why should it then reset too?

Comment: it happens even when i stop and restart the server. it keeps the value. i can't understand why . Kinda new to hibernate

Comment: i think we will need more code to see where the mistake happens

Comment: i have edited it a little. I dont think extra code will make any difference. This all is what is used. Nothing else.